# Swift PhaseAnimator retain cycle

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui

I'm trying to use the new `PhaseAnimator` from iOS 17 and I noticed a bug.
For some reason, the animation is not deallocated when the view is removed from hierarchy, leading to a crash app.

Example

```swift
enum OuterBreathState: CaseIterable {
    case exhale, inhale
    var scale: CGFloat {
        switch self {
            case .inhale: return 2
            case .exhale: return 1
        }
    }
    var color: Color {
        switch self {
            case .inhale: return .white
            case .exhale: return .blue
        }
    }
}

struct PhaseView: View {
    var body: some View {
        PhaseAnimator(OuterBreathState.allCases) { state in
            Circle()
                .background(.clear)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .padding(.vertical)
                .scaleEffect(state.scale)
                .background(in: Circle())
                .foregroundStyle(state.color)
        } animation: {state in
            switch state {
                case .inhale: return .easeInOut(duration: 1.5)
                case .exhale: return .easeInOut(duration: 3.5)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink("push") {
                PhaseView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pushing the view works just fine, but after popping, the app becomes unresponsive 
It's the content update that fails actually. If I make no updates to the Circle, everything works fine.
I also tried with the `phaseAnimator` trailing function, I get the same behaviour.`

Weirdly, if I use a trigger (and even a timer that flips the trigger to mimic the loop), it does not crash.
Here is the code

```swift
enum OuterBreathState: CaseIterable {
    case exhale, inhale
    var scale: CGFloat {
        switch self {
            case .inhale: return 2
            case .exhale: return 1
        }
    }
    var color: Color {
        switch self {
            case .inhale: return .white
            case .exhale: return .blue
        }
    }
}

struct PhaseView: View {
    @State var animate = false
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 5, tolerance: .zero, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()
    var body: some View {
        PhaseAnimator(OuterBreathState.allCases, trigger: animate) { state in
            Circle()
                .background(.clear)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .padding(.vertical)
                .scaleEffect(state.scale)
                .background(in: Circle())
                .foregroundStyle(state.color)
        } animation: {state in
            switch state {
                case .inhale: return .easeInOut(duration: 1.5)
                case .exhale: return .easeInOut(duration: 3.5)
            }
        }
        .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
            animate.toggle()
        })
        .onTapGesture {
            animate.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink("push") {
                PhaseView()
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Any idea why it crashes and how I can make it work ?
Thanks!

Comment: Interesting fact : if I use a trigger, it does not crash. Is a use a timer that flips a boolean trigger to mimic a loop, it does not crash either.